# Link to sort by month

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I would like to have a couple links where you could switch between months in the view that would look something link this:

```
< January 2011 >
```

My table is called "links" and the column I want to sort by is called "deploy_date". The brackets would change the month and only the entries deploying in that current month would be displayed.

I can get it to display the current month but cant give the brackets any function to filter by the deploy_date.

Comment: Can you post the code to your controller action?

Answer (score 1):

I can not give you the exact code.

However, if you only want to change the month and not the year you could link with the brakets to `month + 1` and `month - 1`.

Something like

`link_to '<', controller_path + '&month=(fill in month -1)'`

For > you just do it accordingly.

In the controller you could check for the month param

`params[:month] ? @month = params[:month] : @month = Date.today.month`

From the top of my head I am not too sure about the Date object and if it has the correct methods, sadly I do not have a ruby to test right now.

Hope this helps you a little

Comment: What became of it? Are you still having the problem?